# Why is my flow's "Send an Email" action using a guid instead of calling user's email address

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

The final step of my flow uses "Send an email (V2)" to deliver results to the calling user. It is erroring on the recipient email address:

[image: Error message]

I have also tried the alternative actions "Send email with options" and "Send an email from a shared mailbox (V2)" and both are throwing the same error.

The error title is "OpenApiOperationParameterTypeConversionFailed".

The dynamic content I am using is the only "user email" dynamic I can find:
[image: Action setup]

The flow fails, indicating that "Input parameter 'emailMessage/To' is required to be of type 'String/email' and that the guid provided at runtime (naturally) isn't an email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuing to experiment and research, I found that entering:

```
triggerOutputs()['headers']['x-ms-user-email']
```

...into the **Dynamic Content | Expression** setting is a workaround for this issue though I still do not understand why it is happening.
[image: Workaround illustration]